# Large Number of file concatenation

Tags: linux, file, concatenation, cat

I have around 3-4 million files in a directory filename ending with, say `type1.txt, type2.txt.` (file are `1type1.txt, 1type2.txt,2type2.txt,2type2.txt` etc )

Now I want to concatenate all files ending with type1.txt & type2.txt.

Currently I am doing `cat *type1.txt > allTtype1.txt` similarly for `type2.txt`. 
 I wanted to preserve order in both final output file, it is my guess that `cat` does that. 
 But it is too slow.

Please suggest some faster method to do the same.

Thanks,
 Ravi

Comment: `I have around 3-4 million files in a directory` of dear.

Comment: Which Linux filesystem supports millions of files in a single dir? Ext2/3 can have only 32k entries in a directory AFAIK..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cat` itself is not slow. But every time you expand a shell wild card (? and *), the shell will read and search through all the file names in that directory, which is very slow.

Also the kernel will take time finding the file when you open it by name, which you can not avoid. This depends on the file system in use (unspecified in the question): some file systems are more intelligent with huge directories than others.

To sort this out you might benefit from taking a file listing **once**:

```
ls > /tmp/filelist
```

...and then using `grep` or similar for selecting the files out of that list:

```
cat `grep foo /tmp/filelist` > /out/bar
```

After you have sorted this mess out, make sure to structure your storage/application in such a way that this does not ever happen again. :) Also make sure to to `rmdir` the existing directory after you have gotten your files out of it (using it again for any purpose will not be effective even if there is just a single file in it).

Answer (score 5):

You can do this using this command:

```
ls | while read file; do cat $file >> allTtype${file#*type}; done
```

But as snap said above in his answer, each time `cat` need to open a file, it will have to do an inode lookup which would take a long time in a directory with lots of file.  To try to speed things up, you could cat by inode using [icat](http://www.sleuthkit.org/sleuthkit/man/icat.html) from the [Sleuth Kit](http://www.sleuthkit.org/sleuthkit/):

```
ls -i | while read -a file_array; do icat /dev/sda1 ${file_array[0]} >> allTtype${file_array[1]#*type}; done
```

And even better, you can put the resulting files in another directory:

```
ls -i | while read -a file_array; do icat /dev/sda1 ${file_array[0]} >> /newdir/allTtype${file_array[1]#*type}; done
```